# How to show a previously designed route with a button with android studio using google maps api?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, maps

Hello I'm working on an application for the use of urban transport and I would like to know if it can be done by pressing a `Button` to show a route that I have created not generated by the `API` and if this is possible as the function is called to be able to Investigate about it.

What interests me most is to know if you can draw custom routes on the `MAP` (designed not generated from 2 points)

Thank you

Comment: Why not use polylines for drawing on the map generated?

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate about polylines.